# Discrete Math - Determine the proposition is true or false. $\urcorner\left(p \vee q\right) \wedge \left(\urcorner q \vee r \right)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Give that p is false and q is true and proposition r is false, determine whether the propositions are true. $\urcorner\left(p \vee q\right) \wedge \left(\urcorner q \vee r \right)$

Can I get some feedback on if this is correct and if my syntax for breaking down the answer is good.

$\urcorner\left(p \vee q\right)$ = (p: false $\vee$ q: true) = true, then $\urcorner$($p \vee q$) = false.

$\left(\urcorner q \vee r \right)$ = ($\urcorner$q: false $\vee$ r: false) = true.

$\left(false \wedge  true\right)$ = false, the proposition $\urcorner\left(p \vee q\right) \wedge \left(\urcorner q \vee r \right)$ is false.

Comment: You should have stopped right after knowing that $\neg(p\lor q)$ is false

Comment: @ganeshie8 I think I see what you mean, but I would still have needed to know if the other side was true or false correct; since to FALSE outcomes is still evaluates to TRUE or am I missing some sort of shortcut to reading it?

Comment: $a \land b$ evaluates to false when atleast one of $a$, $b$ is false

Comment: @ganeshie8 thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would simply answer by plugging in and reducing:

Given: $p = F$, $q = T$, $r = F$:

\begin{align}
\neg (p \vee q) \wedge (\neg q \vee r) = &\neg (F \vee T) \wedge (\neg T \vee F) \\
\neg (F \vee T) \wedge (\neg T \vee F) = &\neg T \wedge (F \vee F) \\
=&F\wedge F \\
=& F
\end{align}

So this assignment to $p$, $q$, and $r$ results in the expression evaluating to false.

Comment: thanks, I like this style of putting in the T/F result. Much more easy to read. Much appreciated.